# Mixing stroke width units in SVG

Tags: svg

This seemed to be working before I added a viewBox (which was required since paths are in user units).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="7in" height="7in" viewBox="0 0 7 7">
<rect x="2" y="2" width="1" height="1" style="fill:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
</svg>
```

Now, if I look in inkscape, the stroke-width is 90px (1in). Also, if I specify the rect size or position in inches, it gets a lot bigger (or moves to a bigger coordinate) than I would think it should. I know I'm missing something but reading through the viewbox and viewport docs are not leading me anywhere enlightening (they mostly discuss in terms of pixels). Could someone steer me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the viewBox you have a viewport of 7in square. In CSS [1in is always 96px](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#CSS_units_and_dots-per-inch) so your viewport would be 96 pixels across. If you drew a rect 1in across it would therefore occupy 96 pixels of the screen. (Inkscape may do something different but all browsers use 96px = 1in).

When you add a viewBox you add scaling into the mix. 1px on your drawing may no longer represent 1px on the screen. I.e. 1in on your drawing is still 96px on your drawing but no longer 96 pixels on the screen.

Your current viewBox says that 7px on the screen is now 7in or 7 x 96px so everything on the drawing is magnified by a factor of 96. 1in on the drawing is now 96 x 96 pixels on the screen.

Comment: OK. Very odd. I can deal with it though. I may look at the output of Inkscape to see what it does (probably works on pixels internally?). I may just drop the viewbox but I suspect I'll need it back another time.

Comment: The issue I had is that translate (and other transforms) is in user units but I though it would be good to be consistent so set the user units to be consistent with my document size. I didn't think that this would then make 1 inch be 12 inches (or whatever). I was hoping to have to avoid calculations for scaling (not that I can't. It just seems inelegant)